# send mail after successfull powershell script execution

Tags: windows, email, powershell

So I created the script below:

```
$target = "c:\$(get-date -F 'yyyy-MM')"
if (!(Test-Path $target)) {md $target}
gci 'c:\test\' -Filter *.xml -recurse | ?{!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -ge (get-date "01.$((get-date).Month)")} | copy-item -Destination $target -Force
```

Could somebody point me to the right direction of how to send a email to a specific address after this script was successfully executed ?

Comment: `get-help send-mailmessage`

Answer (score 1):

As arco444 noted in his comment, [`send-mailmessage`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) will allow you to send email from any machine running Powershell v2 or higher, as long as you have an accessible SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below solution in PowerShell

```
 $EmailFrom = "someone1@company.com"
 $EmailTo = "someone2@company.com" 
 $ccUsers="someone3@company.com"  
 $SMTPServer = "smtp.office365.com"
 $port=587     
 $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer,$port) 
 $smtp.EnableSsl = "true"
 $smtp.Credentials =New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($userName, $password); 
 $msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage 
 $msg.From =  $EmailFrom
 $msg.To.Add($EmailTo) 
 $msg.CC.Add($ccUsers)  
 $msg.IsBodyHTML = $true 
 $msg.Subject = "Test Subject";
 #if you want to send some html in your email
 $html = "<html><body><table width='100%'><tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'><td height='25' align='center'> <font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='4'><strong>Test Email from PowerShell</strong></font></td> </tr> </table></body></html>" $msg.Body = $html; $smtp.Send($msg);
```

Answer (score -2):

If your using outlook, here is a example

```
[system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.office.interop.outlook") 
$OL=New-Object -ComObject OUTLOOK.APPLICATION
$ns =$OL.GETNAMESPACE("MAPI")
$mail =$ol.createitem(0)   
$mail.recipients.add("something@live.nl")
$mail.CC=("something@ziggo.nl")
$MAIL.Subject= "$shortname"
#gets a signature
$mail.htmlbody= get-content $env:appdata\Microsoft\Signatures\*.txt       
#for attachments..
$mail.Attachments.Add($file.FullName)

$lines=get-content $filename
$lines+=get-content $env:appdata\Microsoft\Signatures\*.txt      
clear-variable text
foreach ($line in $lines)
{
$text += $line + "`r`n"
}

$mail.body= $text 
$mail.display()
```

Comment: Hi,this script runs on a windows server 2012r2 and should send a mail to an internal exchange server. how can i add this to my script ?

Comment: There is absolutely no need to create a dependency upon Outlook just to send an email from PowerShell.

Comment: i added this snipped to my before mentioned script and it seems to work:

$PSEmailServer = "mailserver.internal.lan"
Send-MailMessage -to "name@domain.com" -from "TESTUSER1 <TESTUSER1@domain.com>" -Subject "TEST SUBJECT" -body "TEST BODY"